# Vertical lines of overlapping points in Seaborn Swarmplot

Tags: python, data, visualization, matplotlib, seaborn

When I plot my data to see its distribution via Swarmplot, these two vertical lines that seems to even overlap occur in the figure.
[image]

It seems to occur even around values that are not that dense, such as around -2.5.
I feel like I might be missing how Swarmplot works but anyone knows the explanation?

Comment: Have you tried adjusting the figsize?

Answer (score 1):

As per the Sea born documentation, -

https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.swarmplot.html

"This function is similar to stripplot(), but the points are adjusted (only along the categorical axis) so that they don’t overlap. This gives a better representation of the distribution of values,

> but it does not scale well to large numbers of observations.

This style of plot is sometimes called a “beeswarm”."

A workaround may be adjusting the `figsize`.